# How to explore with wormhole generator in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

In the Eclipse board game, how do you explore with the wormhole generator? You have to select where you are exploring before you draw a new hex. You must be connected to that empty space with half a wormhole, or a whole wormhole. Does this mean I can explore from an edge of my current hex that does not have a wormhole half as long as I use the wormhole half of the newly drawn hex to connect? Or do I have to explore from an existing wormhole half of the current hex, and I can then connect to an empty edge of the new hex?

Answer (score 6):

You are correct that you must select the unexplored space you wish to explore before drawing the hex tile from the appropriate stack. And yes, if you have the wormhole generator technology, you may explore a space adjacent to a side of your controlled hex that does not have a wormhole half. However, you must then make sure you orient the new hex so that a half wormhole is positioned next to that side of the new hex. If you look at the examples on page 9 of the rulebook the hex marked D, which is a legal placement for a player with a wormhole generator, is an example of the above described situation.